# converting timestamp to nsdate format

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, nsdate

I want to convert my timestamp value `1308031456` to `NSDate` format (which yields the value `Tue, 14 Jun 2011 06:04:16 GMT` in online web conversion). How would I convert between the two programmatically?

Answer (score 147):

**OBJ - C:**
Use [dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:),

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp];
```

**SWIFT:**
Use [init(timeIntervalSince1970:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:)

```
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp)
```

Comment: Depending on the typecasting of timeStamp. Else you could try it like this:

NSDate *beginDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)[[calendarData objectForKey:@"date"] doubleValue]];

Comment: i am also doing it same in swift but getting wrong date..which part i missed it.   var transDate: Double =transDict.valueForKey("date") as! Double
 var tranDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: transDate)
                    
                    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle 
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM dd, y"
                    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation:"CST")
                    let dateValue = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(tranDate) @KingofBliss

Answer (score 18):

You can use the use the method `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` to convert the timestamp you've which is the epoch time.

```
NSDate * myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1308031456];
```

Answer (score 5):

## In obj c

```
double timeStamp = 1513330403393;
NSTimeInterval unixTimeStamp = timeStamp / 1000.0;
NSDate *exactDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixTimeStamp];
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyy hh:mm a";
NSString  *finalate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:exactDate];
```

## In Swift

```
let timeStamp = 1513330403393
let unixTimeStamp: Double = Double(timeStamp) / 1000.0
let exactDate = NSDate.init(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTimeStamp)
let dateFormatt = DateFormatter();
dateFormatt.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyy hh:mm a"
print(dateFormatt.string(from: exactDate as Date))
```

Comment: Please note that code only answers are discouraged. Always add a bit of explanation ... for example not using comments like this - instead put that into well formatted text!

Comment: probably a good idea to just use Date now for swift, also instead of using .init just open `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTimeStamp)` will do

Answer (score 2):

See the various example on date formatting and getting date from timestamp from apple

[Use Formatter Styles to Present Dates and Times With the User’s Preferences](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

[Convert TimeStamp to NSDate in Objective-C](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2011/06/convert-timestamp-to-nsdate-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code piece which lets you convert the unix type timestamp to Formatted Date

```
NSString * timeStampString =@"1304245000";
NSTimeInterval _interval=[timeStampString doubleValue];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
NSString *_date=[_formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

This will print  _date something like 05.03.2011