# iOS reading UTC time with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have a date string like this **"2013-04-25T08:00:00.000+0000"** what is the right way to read it as a date.

I tried all this:

[How to convert NSDate into unix timestamp iphone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997062/how-to-convert-nsdate-into-unix-timestamp-iphone-sdk)

[iOS - Proper formatting of timestamps between mySQL (apache) and iOS (NSDate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065701/ios-proper-formatting-of-timestamps-between-mysql-apache-and-ios-nsdate)

[converting timestamp to nsdate format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407057/converting-timestamp-to-nsdate-format)

and I tried this too:

```
+(NSDate *)dateFromUTCTimeStamp:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
    NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
    NSDate *timeStamp = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return timeStamp;
}
```

everything returns nil, I know I am making a simple mistake but need some help.

Comment: `dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz";` would do fine. Refer the comments of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17010081/767730)

Comment: @Anupdas Thanks a lot, worked like a charm.